# Creating a preview page in CakePHP

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp

I'm building a site in CakePHP, and I'd like to give a 'Preview' option for pages as they're being added or edited.

In the 'Add Page' view, for instance, I have the usual form which the user uses to create their page.  There is a 'Save' button, to save the data.  Next to that, I'd like to have a 'Preview' button, which opens the page in a new window.

So, either I need the controller to open a new window (and I don't think this is possible), or it needs to be a link (targetting a new window) instead of a button - but in that case, how do I POST the data so that it can be shown?  Do I need to use ajax or something?  I'm a total newbie in ajax, but I do have a reasonable grasp of javascript.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If the data that you are previewing is already saved on your database, then you can have an action in your controller (maybe `preview()`) action that references the saved data and loads the preview. And then to use it, you can just use a regular link that targets a new page and opens it there.
This would require saving the data the user is typing to your server every few seconds, though.

If you want to use the data that is still on the page, then you can use a JavaScript function to load a lightbox and populate the contents of that lightbox with data from the fields that the user is working on. You can probably use [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) for that.